# Problems using replaceWith after .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

Probably a simple noob error but I cannot figure it out. I have a submit button and after the user clicks it I want it to disappear and be replaced with "Thanks for submitting your info".

Here's what I have:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#emailsubmit').onClick(function() {
$(this).replaceWith('<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>');

)};
)};

</script>

<input id="emailsubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send " />
```

Looks ok to me, but on click, nothing happens. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the function is `click`, not `onClick`, and you have a couple of syntax errors to boot.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailsubmit').click(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Syntax errors? I can't find a single character in your code that differs from the code in the question, other than the `click`...

Comment: @Guffa: `)}` -> `})`. Yeah, hard to spot with visual diff tools. (Wait, regular people call them eyes?)

Answer (score 0):

You best use `click` instead of `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing inline, DOM-zero events (`onClick`) with jQuery's alias event methods.

jQuery has a `click` method (short for `on('click...`) but no `onClick()` method. This would throw an error, meaning you should always consult your browser console before anything else.

```
$('#emailsubmit').on('click', function() {...
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is named `click` not `onClick`.

Also, removing the submit button will keep the form from being posted. Hide it instead:

```
$(this).hide().after('<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>');
```